# Create a custom vertical axis in a Flex 3 ColumnChart

Tags: apache-flex

I need to create a custom y-axis in a columnChart that resembles a tall / skinny VBox (sorry can't post pictures) and has the axis labels (20, 40, 60, 80, 100) inside the axis.

By default, the y-axis is a line and I have found methods of making the line thicker but I need the labels inside the axis.

I have tried using the AxisRenderer class but can not find any good examples on the proper use. Suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The best thing is to build a custom AxisRenderer that extends the base AxisRenderer class or just extends UIComponent and implements IAxisRenderer.  You can reference the source code for AxisRenderer to see how it draws the axis.  It's in the Flex SDK's frameworks/projects/datavisualization directory.